# how to use a prepostion after "finding"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

there:
Anybody can give me a kind reply for the preposition that could be properly used after "finding". 
My sentense is: I will give you feedback on findings of/on/about/in any significant change of risks.
Thanks!

Comment: Forgive my *saying* so, but verbs *being turned into* nouns is what has caused the clumsiness. Your problem would vanish if "findings" turned back into a verb. "I will give you feedback on/ about any (significant) change of risks I find."

Comment: Thanks, Hugh. I’d like to use the “finding” in this sentence because the finding is from investigation rather than from “I find”. The original meaning I want to express is “work closely with underwriting team and give feedback on findings of/in/on/about significant change with risks”. How do you think about this sentence?

Comment: @hugh By using the verb, the problem doesn't vanish. You've just reduced the number of commonly used prepositions from four to two.

Comment: For me the most suitable word from your list would be 'about', but a better one would be 'concerning'.

Comment: Thanks, about or concerning may be good in the context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be perfectly acceptable to say:

> I will give you feedback on findings of any significant change of risks.

"**...relevant to...**" would change the tone.

> I will give you feedback on findings relevant to any significant change of risks.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't do anything to address the other prepositions asked about. Are you saying that it would *not* be acceptable to use *of*, *about*, or *in*?

Comment: @JasonBassford, Far worse than that, I'm saying this is not a question of grammar, but perhaps Isidore's *ethopoiesis;* or, in plain English, some aspect of transactional linguistics.

Comment: Who's Isidore and what's ethopoiesis?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Isidore of Seville is in Wikipedia. Ethopoiesis is in Isidore's Etymologies.